# function validateTopic(value) not works

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, forms

I want a method in app.component.ts to be called for the (blur) and (change) in app.component.html

**app.component.html**

```
<select (blur)="validateTopic(topic.value)" (change)="validateTopic(topic.value)" required #topic="ngModel" [class.is-invalid]="topic.invalid && topic.touched" class="custom-select" name="topic" [(ngModel)]="userModel.topic">
  <option value='default'>I am interested in</option>
  <option *ngFor="let topic of topics">{{topic}}</option>
</select>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
validateTopic(value)
 {
 if(value==='default')
 {
   this.topicHasError=true;
 }
 else{
   this.topicHasError=false;
 }
}
```

In the VS Code teminal it shows,

```
ERROR in app/app.module.ts(19,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'validateTopic'.
app/app.module.ts(19,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'value'.
app/app.module.ts(21,4): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'value'.
```

In the Browser window it shows,

```
app.module.ts:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: validateTopic is not defined
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.module.ts:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.js:1
```

Comment: Can you please show complete HTML code?

Comment: <select (blur)="validateTopic(topic.value)" (change)="validateTopic(topic.value)" required #topic="ngModel" [class.is-invalid]="topic.invalid && topic.touched" class="custom-select" name="topic" [(ngModel)]="userModel.topic">
  <option value='default'>I am interested in</option>
  <option *ngFor="let topic of topics">{{topic}}</option>
</select>

Answer (score 0):

Your app.component.ts should look like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'whatever',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    validateTopic(value)
    {
     if(value==='default')
     {
       this.topicHasError=true;
     }
     else{
       this.topicHasError=false;
     }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

**app.component.html**

```
<select (blur)="validateTopic($event.target.value)" 
(change)="validateTopic($event.target.value)">
<option value='default'>I am interested in</option>
<option *ngFor="let topic of topics">{{topic}}</option>
</select>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 validateTopic(value) {
    if(value==='default') {

    }
    else
    {     
    console.log(value);
    }
    }
```